# move around single quote in javascript/php

Tags: jquery, filter, single-quotes

Hi I am trying to make dynamic filter on html table which works in general but I am unable to move around single quote in string, I have tried addslashes() in php also regex replace() in javascript but nothing works...don't know if I have to change the filter logic
This is whole javascript code, but I think the problem is within selectField change function function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
function addRemoveClass(theRows){

    theRows.removeClass("odd even");
    theRows.filter(":odd").addClass("odd");
    theRows.filter(":even").addClass("even");

}   

var selVal='';

var rows=$('#myTable tbody tr');

addRemoveClass(rows);


$("#selectField").on("change",function() {
    $('table').show();
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#myTable tbody').find('tr');
    dataset.show();
    // filter the rows that should be hidden
    if(selection!="All"){
        //selection=selection.replace(/'/g, '"');
        selection = selection.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        if(selVal==="First_Name"){
            dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
            //return $(item).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().split(',').indexOf(selection) === -1;
            return $(item).find('td:nth-child(1)').text().indexOf(selection) === -1;
            }).hide();
        } else if(selVal==="Surname"){
            dataset.filter(function(index, item) {  
            return $(item).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().indexOf(selection)=== -1;
            }).hide();
        }
        else if(selVal==="Address"){
            dataset.filter(function(index, item) {
            return $(item).find('td:nth-child(3)').text().indexOf(selection) === -1;
            }).hide();
        }else{
            dataset.show();
        }
    } else{
        dataset.show();     
    }
});



$("#selectCat").on("change",function(){
    var e = document.getElementById("selectCat");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    selVal=strUser;
    $("#selectField").empty();
    //$("#mytBody tr").empty();
    var selected = this.value;
    if(selected !="NoCategory"){
        $.post('process.php', {category:this.value}, function(data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                    var al='All'
                    var options = "";
                        options += "<option value=All selected>All</option>";
                $("#selectField").append(options);

                    options = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {                         
                        //data[i] = data[i].replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                        options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
                        //options += "<option value='" + data[i].toLowercase() + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>";
                    }
                $("#selectField").append(options);
            return false; //prevent from reloading the page
        });

    }else{
        rows.show();
        addRemoveClass(rows);
    }

});
});
```

here is code in html file I am using:

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="filter.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resultdiffversion.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/php" href="process.php" />
<title> Import data </title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

                    <div class="optionDiv">
                    Filter by Category
                    <select id="selectCat">
                        <option value="NoCategory" selected>NoCategory</option>
                        <option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
                        <option value="Surname">Surname</option>
                        <option value="Address">Address</option>
                    </select>

                    Filter by Selected Category
                        <select id="selectField">
                            <option value="All" selected>All</option>   

                    </select>
                </div>  
                <table id="myTable">

                    <thead> 
                    <tr id=HeadRow><th>First_Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Address</th><th>ID</th></tr>                      
                    </thead>  
                <!--    
                    <tr id="HeadRow">  
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>First_Name</th>
                        <th>Surname</th>
                        <th>Address</th> 
                    </tr>
                --> 
                    <tbody> 

                    <tr><td>Michael</td><td>O'Reilly</td><td>581 Beech Street, Lincoln, NE 68506</td><td>246</td></tr><tr><td>Della</td><td>Austin'</td><td>376 Washington Street, Pompano Beach, FL 33060</td><td>247</td></tr><tr><td>Hector</td><td>Hopkins</td><td>442 College Street, East Brunswick, NJ 08816</td><td>248</td></tr><tr><td>Terrance</td><td>Garza'</td><td>737 Route 1, Mahwah, NJ 07430</td><td>249</td></tr><tr><td>Melvin</td><td>Boyd'</td><td>525 Olive Street, Derby, KS 67037</td><td>250</td></tr><tr><td>Kimberly</td><td>Alvarez'</td><td>269 Olive Street, Redondo Beach, CA 90278</td><td>251</td></tr><tr><td>Eleanor</td><td>Steele'</td><td>447 Canal Street, Goose Creek, SC 29445 </td><td>252</td></tr><tr><td>Elsa</td><td>Osborne'</td><td>894 Pheasant Run, Pottstown, PA 19464</td><td>253</td></tr><tr><td>Cameron</td><td>Huff'</td><td>416 Parker Street, Riverdale, GA 30274</td><td>254</td></tr><tr><td>Essie</td><td>Ray'</td><td>539 Devon Court, Woodhaven, NY 11421</td><td>255</td></tr><tr><td>I'Am</td><td>TheBest</td><td>MyStreet 75</td><td>256</td></tr><tr><td>Bilbo</td><td>Baggins</td><td>Shire</td><td>257</td></tr><tr><td>Larry</td><td>I'Connol</td><td>Larrys's Street 45</td><td>258</td></tr><tr><td>Martin</td><td>O'Bannon</td><td>Martins's Street, 56</td><td>259</td></tr>
```

and this is result when I try to filter name with single quote [image: filter on O'Reilly takes everyone with name starting on "O" because Single quote in name cuts the string after "O" so Index of returns 1 three times]

*filter on O'Reilly takes everyone with name starting on "O" because Single quote in name cuts the string after "O" so Index of returns 1 three times*

Comment: Please set up a jsfiddle which provides jquery and html with a few targeted and non-targeted rows.  Something is wrong or missing from your provided code because `selVal` is never declared before it is used in the condition statements.  If you do not provide a question with code that can replicate the error, your question may be ignored, downvoted, and/or closed.  Help us help you.

Comment: I have added all of the code I am using except first html file which contains simple button only

Comment: Oh dear lord no.  Remove all that php and css.  You are meant to offer the bare minimum information to allow replication of the problem.  I would like to see ONLY the source code html and the jquery.  Please update your question before the cranky downvoters come.

Comment: ok I have removed most of php code and left only javascript and html...I am sorry I may be lost cause but I don't know If I provided it correctly now...but I have removed also php part used for json...that works however

Comment: Two things I need to see are: the table data (you still have that in database-fed php).  Load your page, access the source html code, and copy a few rows of the table including the O'Reilly row and add it to your question AND did you notice that your javascript declares `selVal='';` nothing happens to it, then it is checked to match `First_Name`, etc.  You need to fix this portion.

Comment: I have inserted the code from source page, hope I understood you correctly, for the selVal=' '; variable it is filled in the second on change function for #selectCat filter....however that one is linked to other simple php file using JSON for running sql query to populate selector according to chosen category but I don't know if I need to insert the JSON part code since you told me to remove all the php code....And also I want to thank you for the patience you still have with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my comments in the jquery.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mickmackusa/pLkwbsqu/)

Here is the html I used in the demo:

```
<div class="optionDiv">
    Filter by Category
    <select id="selectCat">
        <option value="NoCategory">NoCategory</option>
        <option value="First_Name">First_Name</option>
        <option value="Surname" selected>Surname</option>
        <option value="Address">Address</option>
    </select>
    Filter by Selected Category
    <select id="selectField">
        <option value="All" selected>All</option>   
        <option value="O'Reilly">O'Reilly</option>
    </select>
</div>  
<table id="myTable">
    <thead> 
        <tr id=HeadRow><th>First_Name</th><th>Surname</th><th>Address</th><th>ID</th></tr>                      
    </thead>  
    <tbody> 
        <tr><td>Michael</td><td>O'Reilly</td><td>581 Beech Street, Lincoln, NE 68506</td><td>246</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Della</td><td>Austin'</td><td>376 Washington Street, Pompano Beach, FL 33060</td><td>247</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Hector</td><td>Hopkins</td><td>442 College Street, East Brunswick, NJ 08816</td><td>248</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Terrance</td><td>Garza'</td><td>737 Route 1, Mahwah, NJ 07430</td><td>249</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Melvin</td><td>Boyd'</td><td>525 Olive Street, Derby, KS 67037</td><td>250</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Kimberly</td><td>Alvarez'</td><td>269 Olive Street, Redondo Beach, CA 90278</td><td>251</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Eleanor</td><td>Steele'</td><td>447 Canal Street, Goose Creek, SC 29445 </td><td>252</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Elsa</td><td>Osborne'</td><td>894 Pheasant Run, Pottstown, PA 19464</td><td>253</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cameron</td><td>Huff'</td><td>416 Parker Street, Riverdale, GA 30274</td><td>254</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Essie</td><td>Ray'</td><td>539 Devon Court, Woodhaven, NY 11421</td><td>255</td></tr>
        <tr><td>I'Am</td><td>TheBest</td><td>MyStreet 75</td><td>256</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bilbo</td><td>Baggins</td><td>Shire</td><td>257</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Larry</td><td>I'Connol</td><td>Larrys's Street 45</td><td>258</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Martin</td><td>O'Bannon</td><td>Martins's Street, 56</td><td>259</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
function addRemoveClass(theRows){
    theRows.removeClass("odd even");
    theRows.filter(":odd").addClass("odd");
    theRows.filter(":even").addClass("even");
}   
var selVal='';
var rows=$('#myTable tbody tr');
addRemoveClass(rows);
$("#selectField").on("change",function() {
    $('table').show();
    var selection = $(this).val();
    var dataset = $('#myTable tbody').find('tr');
    var selVal = $('#selectCat').val();  // Mick added this
    dataset.show();
    // filter the rows that should be hidden
    if(selVal!="All"){  // Mick added this
    // if(selection!="All"){  // Mick removed this
        console.log(selection+' & '+selVal);  // Mick added this
        // Mick says no escaping needed
        //selection=selection.replace(/'/g, '"');
        //selection = selection.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
        if(selVal=="Surname"){
            dataset.filter(function(index, item) {  
                console.log(index+' & '+item+' & '+selection);  // Mick added this
                return $(item).find('td:nth-child(2)').text().indexOf(selection)=== -1;
            }).hide();
        }else{
            dataset.show();
        }
    }else{
        dataset.show();     
    }
});
```

Comment: @Vlad67 If this sufficiently solves your problem, please award my answer the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful).  If there is anything unclear or wrong, leave a comment and I will check my computer when I wake up.

Comment: Hi it did work in the Demo you have posted. I copied the code in your Demo and it worked as well...so I was able to figure out that the problem was probably in the bottom #selectCat on change function in how Options options += "<option value='" + data[i] + "'>" + data[i] + "</option>"; are sent in to html file. and the problem were those freaking single quotes in statement above....so correctly it is supposed to be options += "<option value=" + data[i] + ">" + data[i] + "</option>"; and now it works, thanks for your help and patience I really appreciate it :)